# ASP.NET [[Url]] Data attribute - change validation to not accept ftp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

ASP.NET's built in [Url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.urlattribute?view=netcore-3.1) data attribute validates that a url starts with http, https or ftp.

> "The Url field is not a valid fully-qualified http, https, or ftp
> URL."

Whats the best way to modify the validation to, say, only http / https or perhaps just https?

Creating a custom validation attribute is the obvious way forward but perhaps there is an easier way for what must be a common requirement?

Answer (score 1):

According to the url attribute [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/f07730eedb1f7e2cb5e178d988bc2255f7ce7021/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs#L19-L30), we could find that the check logic is very simple and it's a sealed class. That means we couldn't inherit from it.  In my opinion, the most easily way is create a custom validation attribute.  Details about how to create a custom validate, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes).

```
namespace System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter,
        AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class UrlAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
    {
        public UrlAttribute()
            : base(DataType.Url)
        {
            // Set DefaultErrorMessage not ErrorMessage, allowing user to set
            // ErrorMessageResourceType and ErrorMessageResourceName to use localized messages.
            DefaultErrorMessage = SR.UrlAttribute_Invalid;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return value is string valueAsString &&
                (valueAsString.StartsWith("http://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || valueAsString.StartsWith("https://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || valueAsString.StartsWith("ftp://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage example from a Model class

```
[CustomUrl(CustomUrlAttribute.UrlTypes.Http | CustomUrlAttribute.UrlTypes.Https)]
public string Url {get; set;}
```

Won't provide any client side validation though

CustomUrlAttribute.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DataAnnotations
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | 
     AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class CustomUrlAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {

        [Flags]
        public enum UrlTypes
        {
            Http  = 1,
            Https = 2,
            Ftp   = 4,
        }

        public CustomUrlAttribute(UrlTypes urlType)
        {
            UrlType = urlType;
        }

        public UrlTypes UrlType { get; }            

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
                                                    ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return ValidationResult.Success;

            if (value is string valueAsString)
            {
                if (Uri.TryCreate(valueAsString, UriKind.Absolute, 
                                  out Uri validatedUri))
                {
                    // validatedUri contains a valid Uri. Check for the scheme
                    switch (validatedUri.Scheme)
                    {
                        case "http":
                            if (UrlType.HasFlag(UrlTypes.Http))
                                return ValidationResult.Success;
                            break;
                        case "https":
                            if (UrlType.HasFlag(UrlTypes.Https))
                                return ValidationResult.Success;
                            break;
                        case "ftp":
                            if (UrlType.HasFlag(UrlTypes.Ftp))
                                return ValidationResult.Success;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(validationContext));
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (ErrorMessage == null)
            {
                string schemes = String.Join(", ", GetFlags(UrlType)).ToLowerInvariant();
                return $"The field {validationContext.DisplayName} is not" + 
                        " a valid fully-qualified URL ({schemes})";
            }
            else
                return ErrorMessage;
        }

        static IEnumerable<Enum> GetFlags(Enum input)
        {
            foreach (Enum value in Enum.GetValues(input.GetType()))
                if (input.HasFlag(value))
                    yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```